# SoftwareLicensingProduct Which one is my

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I need to check whether the OS needs activation,
my following code displays a multitude of "channels".

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
               new ManagementObjectSearcher
    (
    "root\\CIMV2",
    "SELECT 
    Description,
    LicenseIsAddon,
    LicenseStatus 
    FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct 
    WHERE LicenseIsAddon = False"
    );

        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
        {
            if (queryObj["Description"].ToString().ToLower().Contains("operating"))
            {
                foreach (var item in queryObj.Properties)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
                }
            }
        }
        Console.Write("***done***");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How do i know which one to check in order to determine if i need to activate the OS?

Or is my only way to see, if i have any LicenseStatus = 1 in there? Which of course can be wrong if there is one activated and one not activated OS installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being i filtered the channels a bit more and concluded, that this is good enough:

```
private void getOSActivation()
{
   try
   {
     ManagementObjectSearcher LicenseSearcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT LicenseStatus,Description FROM SoftwareLicensingProduct");

     foreach (ManagementObject LSObj in LicenseSearcher.Get())
     {
       OStestString = LSObj["Description"].ToString().ToLower();
       if (
           OStestString.Contains("operating") 
           &&
           // next line is new
           (OStestString.Contains("slp") || OStestString.Contains("dm"))
          )
          {
            foreach (var item in LSObj.Properties)
            {
              OSresults.Add(LSObj["LicenseStatus"].ToString());
            }
          }
        }
      }
    catch (Exception LSOexception)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(LSOexception.Message);
    }
  }
```